# How to select elements in a Quick union operation?

Tags: data-structures, disjoint-sets, union-find

There are a set of elements S = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}. Here there are 10 elements (N = 10). An array arr to manage the connectivity of the elements. Arr[ ] that is indexed by elements of sets, which are of size N (as N elements in set), used to manage the operations of union and find.

https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/disjoint-data-strutures/basics-of-disjoint-data-structures/tutorial/

What I cant understand is how are the elements selected to start with union operation? In this Link(mentioned above) the union has started with (2,1) , can I use any two elements? say (1,8)? I don't seem to get the same tree as explained in the image if I start with selecting different elements(other than Union(2,1)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You typically perform *Union* and *Find* operations as required by the task you are solving. For example, one way to test if an undirected graph contains a cycle is to consider its edges one by one. When considering an edge (*u*, *v*) we:

1. Ask the question: are *u* and *v* already connected? That translates to two operations, *Find*(*u*) and *Find*(*v*). If *Find*(*u*) = *Find*(*v*), then the edge (*u*, *v*) is part of a cycle and the algorithm terminates with the answer "yes".
2. Mark *u* and *v* (along with their respective sets) as connected, so that they are not connected again in the future. That translates to the operation *Union*(*u*, *v*).

At the end, if no cycles were found, the algorithm terminates with the answer "no".

Comment: @Cātālin Thanks for your response, I am just getting started with DSA in depth as I proceed towards my masters degree. I am currently following the Algorithms part 1 course by robert sedgewick on Coursera. The content and approach in the course often gets confusing for me as I am a non CS student ( In bachelor's).